# Accessing parameters of Iframe src in visualforce page from lightning componenet

Tags: visualforce, lightning

How can I access parameters passed from iframe src in Visualforce page.
Lightning Page Iframe:

```
<iframe src="{!v.VFUrl}" width="100%"  height="500px;"  frameBorder="0"/
```

In VF page trying to access like:

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(        
    
'{!$RemoteAction.GPD_StakeholderSchedulerPageController.getStakeholder}',
    '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.projectId}',
         function(results, event){...
}
```

But unable to access, is there anything i'm wrongdoing.
Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options of passing iframe params.

First Options :

Add your params as a query param to the iframe url (`v.VFUrl}`). `iframeURL.page?accountId=6573498576453&secondParam=4566456`

Then from VFPage you can access.

```
var url = new URL(window.localtion.href);
var c = url.searchParams.get("accountId");
var d = url.searchParams.get("secondParam");
```

Second Option:

Use `window.postMessage` from lightning component.